# How-to: Prevent KendoDropDownList from converting selected value to string

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, type-conversion

I have a KendoDropDownList with a data source of a list of objects, like:

```
[{"Id":1,"Text":"Item One"},{"Id":2,"Text":"Item Two"}]
```

Notice that the item's `Id` property is a number and not a string.

If I check the value of the bound input before selecting from the list I receive a number.
After selecting an item from this list I receive text (a number wrapped in quotes).

This is troubling, especially in scenarios where there is a 'hasChanges' flag.

How can I modify this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo UI isn't responsible for this behavior, HTML is. All `<select/>` option values and `<input/>` values are treated as strings in markup. Check out the code below and the accompanying jsFiddle to see the difference.

**HTML**

```
<select id="test"></select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var data = [{"Id":1,"Text":"Item One"}, {"Id":2,"Text":"Item Two"}]

$('#test').kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: data,
    dataTextField: 'Text',
    dataValueField: 'Id'
});

$('#test').on('change', function() {
  var value,
      item; 

  value = $(this).val();
  item = $(this).data('kendoDropDownList').dataItem();

  alert(
      'HTML ' + value + ' is a ' + typeof value + '\n' +
      'Object ' + item.Id + ' is a ' + typeof item.Id
  );
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/pd9FS/1/**